# How to define a minor mode that uses specified input-method in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I want to use korean characters in Emacs, so I installed [hangul.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/hangul.el).
I can activate input-method by '(set-input-method "korean-hangul")'.

And I want to define a mode that have the `korean-hangul' input method.

I only know how to define a minor mode with a defined map-key like this.
`(easy-mmode-define-minor-mode korean-mode "Mode for korean" nil  " 한" korean-mode-map)`

But I don't know how to connect a input-method and a minor-mode.
I'll add add some key-bindings to the `korean-mode`.

How can I define a mode like this `korean-mode`?